Linear dimensions of pdf picture
I have this sample program:
\documentclass[border=0cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) node () {\includegraphics[width=50cm,height=50cm]{example-image-a}};
        \draw (50,0) node () {\includegraphics[width=50cm,height=50cm]{example-image-b}};
        \draw (0,50) node () {\includegraphics[width=50cm,height=50cm]{example-image-a}};
        \draw (50,50) node () {\includegraphics[width=50cm,height=50cm]{example-image-b}};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}

The result expected for the pdf picture is 100cmx100cm.
But I have this result:

Note the real dimensions in the lower left corner:

Why not 100cmx100cm?

I believe that that tikzpicture has padding by default. I didn't check it precisely, but using \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt] ... \end{tikzpicture} could fix the issue.

@M.AlJumaily probably yes. and outer sep too.

The two comment answers almost to my question. I have now, with the two corrections: W=100,011 cm and H=100,005cm.

Not entirely sure about standalones behaviour if you don't use the tikz-class option, but you might get spurious spaces around the tikzpicture environment as well.

I think the problem is \includegraphics[]{} : each picture I make with the tikz give me the desired exat result; 50.000 cm,100.000 cm, etc. .When I put these pictures togheter with \includegraphics, I have spurius results.

the nodes have padding rather than the picture, I think, but you are also drawing with default line width and, even though you aren't drawing anything but a point, I don't know if standalone or tikz realises that. but also what @Skillmon said: uncommented spaces in standalone certainly can show up, though I don't remember the details. if you need to be absolutely within 100cm, take at least 1pt off the total to allow for inaccuracies. that shouldn't be too much of an issue here, though, as there's not a lot of calculation - but there are some, of course.

already \includegraphics[width=50cm,height=50cm]{example-image-a} has rounding errors and will give a size of 50,006 x 49,999.

@UlrikeFischer Yes. I have already written this in my previous comment.

@cfr I don't need exact value 100.000cm . I just reported the inattended results.

@RaffaeleSantoro Then you have your answer. Remove space added by PGF/TikZ with inner sep and outer sep set to zero and that's the clostest PGF/TikZ can get you. Everything else is due to the inprecise nature of TeX mathematics. I get an error of 0.11 mm and 0.05mm. I'd consider that close enough for any normal document. You can now use that error and remove those from the widths and heights of the \includegraphics for a trial-and-error solution.

@Qrrbrbirlbel Certainly I am happy with the two errors 0.11 mm and 0.05 mm. For me the question is closed. Thanks.

it's not really \includegraphics versus tikz. it's that you are doing dimension calculations with TeX. if you do something similar in tikz, you get the same inaccuracies. that is, the imprecision is in the underlying system and not either of the packages, which just use that system. for higher accuracy, you can use one of the floating point implementations e.g. in expl3, but that's not generally needed unless the inaccuracies accumulate.

@cfr Well and if the game is worth the candle how I can correct my little example to avoids the inaccuracies resulting from my little program?

@RaffaeleSantoro well, I do not know if you can persuade \includegraphics to use greater accuracy. in expl3, you can use the fp module. in 2e, you can use \fpeval. so in tikz, you could use that. or you could load e.g. the floating point library provided by tikz. (but note that the latter can cause some side-effects.) in tikzpictures, it is usually possible to structure the code differently to mitigate the inaccuracies sufficiently. but it is only worth doing when it is worth doing, imho. I wouldn't do it unless the inaccuracies are actually causing problems.
